# Plugin which works when in app/assets can't be found in lib

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins

I have a javascript file from a plugin I downloaded (http://www.datatables.net/) in my lib folder. Specifically, in app/lib/assets/javascripts/datatables/datatables.js (This is the file jquery.dataTables.min.js which I renamed because I thought it might be having problems because I was trying to require the whole bit jquery/dataTables.min).

I have the following in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require lib/assets/javascripts/datatables
//= require_tree .
```

I also tried it

```
//= require datatables
```

instead of lib/assets/javascripts/datatables

I'm getting an error that Sprockets cannot find the file datatables in c:/Sites/my-app-name/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
It doesn't seem to be looking in lib/assets. The plugin worked when I put it in the /app/assets/javascripts directory to try it, but I know that isn't where it is really supposed to go. I also tried it in the vendor directory, which didn't work AND gave me a notice on the server that for Rails 4.0 it would need to be in the lib directory.

Fixes I have researched and tried, which failed:

1. Restarting the server (as the first attempt at fixing it, and after every fix I've tried.)
2. Including

   config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
   in /app/config/application.rb
3. Moving the file from lib/assets/javascripts/datatables.js to lib/assets/javascripts/datatables/datatables.js
4. Creating an index.js file in lib/assests/javascripts/datatables/ with the following:

   //= require datatables
   //= require_tree .
5. In app/javascripts/application.js requiring just the filename, or requiring the pathway.
   I tried

   //= require datatables

   //= require lib/assets/javascripts/datatables

   //= require /lib/assets/javascripts/datatables/datatables

When I put in /lib/assets/javascripts/datatables/datatables, I didn't get the error message, and my page loaded up. However, the plug-in wasn't working, the site looked like it would if it didn't have the plugin. This is the only thing (besides putting the .js plugin file in the app/assets/javascripts/ dir that altered the error message at all. Otherwise it was the same error message.

Is there a solution which I haven't thought of that I ought to try? Is lib the right place for it?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//= require datatables/datatables
```

This is all you need in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file to load a file at `lib/assets/javascripts/datatables/datatables.js`

What I like to do is maintain an `lib/assets/javascripts/lib.js` file and a `vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor.js` file.

Inside my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file I simply have

```
//= require vendor
//= require lib
```

The `datatables/` directectory really belongs in `vendor/assets/javascripts/`, not in your `lib/` directory. From the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)**

> - `lib/assets` is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.
> - `vendor/assets` is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.

Once you move this directory, inside your `vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor.js` you could add

```
//= require datatables/datatables
```

---

Finally, though you seem to have made an admirable effort to solve your problem on your own, it seems you may have not read through the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)** on the Asset Pipeline - something you should consider doing if you have not yet.

Comment: Thank you. That got it working. I read through part of the Rails Guide on the Asset Pipeline, but since I was just trying to get this bit working, I stopped when they started talking about CSS. I'll go back and read the whole thing. I put them in the library since I had gotten a warning that the vendor directory will no longer be supported when we update to rails 4 and to put them in the lib dir. I've moved them to vendor for now. Thank you again.

Comment: You can 'thank' me by up-voting & accepting my answer. As for the `vendor/` directory 'no longer being supported', I think you read about `vendor/plugins/` support, not `vendor/assets/`. See the **[Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-vendor-plugins)** again.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. I read about it on the server when I tried to stick it in vendor/plugins/. I'm going to need to figure out how to navigate Rails Guide better then, I guess. Thank you for your help. I'm pretty new at this, it's my first app (I inherited the code for it though and am the sole dev at this point).